# jQuery/AJAX automatic population of values

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

I have a problem with *jQuery* and *AJAX*.
I have 3 select tags with values which are populated through *AJAX*.

Here is the case I need.

When I select option on first select tag I get specific values in the second select tag.
Then when I select option on second tag I get specific values in the third select tag.
After I select option in third select tag - submit happens.
This part works.

Of course after submit everything resets. I didn't want that so I've put selected in select tag.  Now I don't know how to **"live"** read from first and second select tag so that after submit options stays populated.

**Here is my code *PHP/HTML* code:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST" name="userVideos" id="userVideos" style="width: 580px; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">
        <select name="brand_select" id="brand_select" style="width: 140px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <option value="">Select Brand</option>

            <?php
            $query_brands = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM users_video WHERE location = '2' ORDER BY brand");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query_brands))
            {
                $name = $row->brand;  
                $sel = ($_POST['brand_name'] == $name) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
                echo "<option value='{$row->brand}' $sel>{$row->brand}</option>";   
            }
            ?>

        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['brand_select']); ?>" name="brand_name" id="brand_name"/>

        <select name="series_select" id="series_select" style="width: 140px; margin-right: 20px;" disabled>
            <option value="">Select Series</option>

            <?php
            //TODO: finish code tidification
            $sel = ($_POST['series_name'] != "") ? "selected='selected'" : "";
            echo "<option value='" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['series_name']) . "' $sel>" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['series_name']) . "</option>";
            ?>

        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="series_name" id="series_name"/>

        <select name="model_select" id="model_select" style="width: 140px;  margin-right: 20px;" disabled>
            <option value="">Select Model</option>

            <?php
            $sel = ($_POST['model_name'] != "") ? "selected='selected'" : "";
            echo "<option value='" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['model_name'] != "") . "' $sel>" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['model_name']) . "</option>";
            ?>

        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="model_name" id="model_name"/>
    </form>
```

**And here is my *jQuery* code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var brand = "";
var series = "";
var model = "";
var _brand = "";
_brand = $('#brand_name').val();

$("#brand_select").live("change", function(){ 
    brand = $('select#brand_select').val();


    if (brand == "" && _brand == "")
    {
        $('select#series_select').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#model_select').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $('select#series_select').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#brand_name').val(brand);

        var grbData = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "series.php",
            data: "brand=" + brand,
            success: function(html){
                $("#series_select").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});

$("#series_select").change(function(){
    series = $('select#series_select').val();
    if (series != ""){
        $('#model_select').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#series_name').val(series);

        var newData = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "model.php",
            data: "brand=" + brand + "&series=" + series,
            success: function(html){
                $("#model_select").html(html);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#model_select').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});

$("#model_select").change(function(){
    model = $('select#model_select').val();
    if (model != ""){
        $('#model_name').val(model);
        $('#userVideos').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have the backed fill in the values. No need to have the client fill them in when the backed knows what was picked

Comment: Can you elaborate or give me some example? Thx.

Comment: Too much clutter, too much non-relevant code. Please, clean your code to the bare minimum to illustrate to what you want. This helps others to analyse the problem (rather then spending a lot of time trying to understand non-relevant things) and answer to the actual problem. Heck, by stripping down a problem, you might even find the solution yourself (have an insight yourself).

Comment: what epascarello said - first part works because you aren't submitting the form - jquery is working on the same dom as you go. As soon as you click submit, though, you're posting the form to the server, and getting back (essentially) a brand new page. You could either 1. not post the form (instead using ajax to submit the values) -- this is not really the "correct" way to do things. Or 2. accept the fact that you're getting a new page back from the server, but have it (the server) fill in the values before sending it back to client; it knows the values after all -- this is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for simplicity. Give them all the same class but use id for Brand or Series. I'm writing this without testing sorry but you can move all you functions into 1. Basic Idea you will need to tweak. Also I may have even over complicated it with static variables. But at least you can keep track of the values.

```
$(".series_select").change(function(){
var value = $(this).val(),
    type = $(this).attr('id'),
    data,
    self = $(this);
    if(type == "brand"){
    data = "brand=" + value;
    $(".series_select").change.brand = value;
   } else if (type == "series"){
    data = "brand=" + $(".series_select").change.brand + "&series=" + value;
    $(".series_select").change.series = value;
   } else if( type == "submit"){
      if($(".series_select").change.brand != '' && $(".series_select").change.series != ''){
      $('#userVideos').submit();
       return;
      }
 }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "model.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
            self.html(html);
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thx everyone for answers and good ideas which led me to the right path!